# DIsplaying graph using knock out and kendo chart

Tags: knockout.js, charts, kendo-ui

I need to display a graph using kendo chart and knockout js. However the graph is not displayed in the page. Any help to the problem would be greatful.

Below is the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="countrygraph" class="k-chart" style="position: relative; touch-action: none; " data-bind="kendoChart: { data: CountryUsers, title: { text: '' }, legend:{position: 'top'},series: UserCount, seriesColors: ['lightgreen'], axisDefaults: {categories:CountryName } }"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the js file .

```
function CountryModel() {

self = this;
self.CountryUsers = ko.observableArray([]);

function addUserCountry(countryName, userCount) {
        return {
            CountryName: ko.observable(countryName),
            UserCount: ko.observable(userCount)
        }
    }

self.CountryUsers().push(new addUserCountry('india',1));
self.CountryUsers().push(new addUserCountry('usa',2));
self.CountryUsers().push(new addUserCountry('uk',1));

}


$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new CountryModel());
});
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with Kendo but where are you initializing the graph ? Or maybe it's improved and doesn't require javascript initialization. Also, where are you defining `self`?

Comment: i have initialised the self. However i want to know what need to be done to display the grpah